# Is it safe to assign an object of type java.sql.Date to a variable of java.util.Date?

Tags: java, sql, datetime, java-7

In our DB access layer, we are using the data type `java.sql.Date` for representing `DATE` columns, whereas in our beans, we are using `java.util.Date` (it's a legacy application).

Since `java.sql.Date` extends `java.util.Date`, is it safe to just set the `java.sql.Date` objects we obtain from the DB layer in our beans like this?

```
java.sql.Date sqlDate;
// bean.setValidFrom(java.util.Date validFrom)
bean.setValidFrom(sqlDate);
```

The code compiles just fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No**, *it is not safe*. Even though `java.sql.Date extends java.util.Date`, it is not a proper sub-type since it is not a behavioral subtype. Here's an example showing how the two types behave differently:

```
// not really a date, but a Date
Date date1 = new Date(0L);                                   
// really a date, but not a Date
java.sql.Date sqlDate = java.sql.Date.valueOf("1970-01-01"); 
// really a date, but a Date?
Date date2 = sqlDate;                                        
// a Date with time
date1.getHours();                                            
// a Date without time. <-- throws an IllegalArgumentException. 
// Wait, exactly *which* argument is illegal?
date2.getHours();
```

You should create a new object of type `java.util.Date`, copying the value like this:

```
java.sql.Date dateFromDb;
bean.setValidFrom(new java.util.Date(dateFromDb.getTime()));
```

Fortunately, things got a lot better with Java 8.

Comment: You shouldn't assume that there is any hour / minute / second information available on a `java.sql.Date`. That might be the case only because `Date` is really a `java.time.LocalDate`, i.e. a date with a timezone offset. If you're using Oracle, this `java.sql.Date` vs. `java.sql.Timestamp` mess will bite you in various ways. [Using `Timestamp` will have negative effects on your execution plan, for instance](http://blog.jooq.org/2014/12/22/are-you-binding-your-oracle-dates-correctly-i-bet-you-arent/).

Comment: (Just to be sure, the reason why I said this is because you shouldn't even rely on `java.sql.Date.getTime()`. The only reliable thing in that type is `toString()`, `toLocalDate()` and `valueOf()`)